# jQuery like event maps for Backbone listenTo?

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-views, backbone-events

I have a view which needs to listenTo the change of a model attribute. When that change event fires, I have to call two different callback functions. I know this can be easily accomplished using .on like

```
model.on({
     'change:title' : updateTitle,
     'change:title' : updateSummary
});
```

But when using listenTo I have to write this in multiple lines

```
this.listenTo(model, 'change:title', updateTitle);
this.listenTo(model, 'change:title', updateSummary);
```

Is there a way to avoid having to re-write the listenTo statement multiple times? 
Or does this issue mean that my code isn't structured properly and I should rethink my approach?

A simple alternative is that I call updateSummary from updateTitle, but I was just wondering if this can be accomplished using object.listenTo

Comment: That `model.on` call **will not** work as the keys in a JavaScript objects are unique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> > does this issue mean that my code isn't structured properly and I should rethink my approach?

I don't see any problem having two (or more) listeners registered to the same event. That's a core point of decoupling. You could have different (decoupled) Views that update their contents when the same event is triggered.

I don't know the rest of your code, but I suppose your `updateSummary` listens to other change events apart from the `change:title`:

```
this.listenTo(model, 'change:summary', updateSummary);
```

In this case you are registering the same listener (`updateSummary`) to different events (`change:title` and `change:summary`). And that's ok, with `listenTo` you are sort of *connecting* different view updates to different model events in a decoupled way.

> > Is there a way to avoid having to re-write the listenTo statement multiple times?

Maybe an overkill, but you could use the functions that underscore provides to have something like this:

```
_.each([updateTitle, updateSummary], _.partial(this.listenTo, model, 'change:title'), this);
```

> > A simple alternative is that I call updateSummary from updateTitle, but I was just wondering if this can be accomplished using object.listenTo

I'm afraid that `listenTo` only accepts a callback function, not an array of functions.

If you are still worried about having `listenTo` on the same event multiple times, you can create a more general function, let's say `update`, that updates both *title* and *summary*, and register only this more general update function:

```
this.listenTo(model, 'change:title', update);
```

or if you don't want another function, you can use an anonymous one:

```
this.listenTo(model, 'change:title', function() {updateTitle(); updateSummary();});
```

Comment: Thanks! I am going to stick with multiple listeners for same event. I wasn't sure if there is a better/cleaner way to handle the scenario. Your answer is extremely thorough and goes in depth to explain the alternative approaches that I could take.

Answer (score 1):

As @muistooshort already mentioned in the comment :

```
var objParam={
     'change:title' : updateTitle,
     'change:title' : updateSummary
};
model.on(objParam);
```

See carefully, `objParam` has 2 **keys with the same name**, this will give error in `strict` mode, otherwise will just override the previous value of the key & hence, `console.log(objParam)` prints

```
{         'change:title' : updateSummary    }
```

and this is what passed as argument to the `.on` call.

Comment: Thanks to both you and @mu-is-too-short for pointing that out. Such a silly thing I overlooked.